# How to offset this shower drain

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I'm installing a new acrylic shower pan and the drain pipe is off an inch from where the new pan needs it to be. I don't have a ton of room to make adjustments here. I want to use a [mechanical seal drain](https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey--140-series-101-pnc-plastic-nocalk-shower-drain-1402493307?filter=) instead of a solvent weld drain so that there's not as much stress for this DIYer to set the pan perfectly on the first try. So that rules out [an offset drain](https://www.oatey.com/products/oatey103-series-offset-shower-drain-receptor-base-1301469814?filter=). **Are there any fittings I could use to create the inch offset I need here?**

I thought about two 22.5 degree elbows, but that takes up too much height. My only other thought would be to replace the trap to adjust the angle, but off to the right (in the pic) are a lot of other fittings that all tie into the main, and it seems like that would be a way more complicated route.

The drain pipe is 2".

[image: Shower drain pipe][image]

Comment: If you can cut it in a place where it can be acceptably coupled, replacing the trap is not particularly difficult and completely solves the problem.  You should also include the size of your drain line as it's not obvious from the picture.

Comment: Is that a pair of stacked 2x4s acting as a floor joist, then cut all the way through? Please tell me it's not! Also, which way does the drain need to move?

Comment: @KH I've added a second pic to show more of the drain pipe. The drain is 2".

Comment: @FreeMan the drain needs to move towards the top of the pic, so deeper into the cut in the joist.

Comment: Unfortunately I'd probably be cutting out that entire assembly and reworking it. There's no good place to splice. That's not too bad a project, though.

Comment: If that's truly a floor joist and not just a nailer for the edge of a piece of flooring, _now_ is the time to stop worrying about the plumbing and focus on fixing a floor joist that has been completely cut through! TBF, there is another joist just a few inches away, but, nobody puts joists that close together just for fun - there's a reason it's there.

Comment: If it's _only_ a nailer to support the edges of subfloor that just fell at an awkward location, then it's probably nothing much to worry about and you could probably safely cut more of it away if you needed more room.

Comment: @FreeMan yeah, I wasn't happy when I saw that the plumbers had cut through the floor joist... but honestly, it's been that way for 30 years and there's a support beam a few feet away running perpendicular to the joists. So while obviously not ideal, I'm not going to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find no fittings to do what I needed to. I ended up cutting the entire assembly off at the main and rebuilding it from scratch to gain the inch I needed.